# Wireguard connectivity between two WSL2 instances (W10) same LAN

Tags: linux, networking, wsl2, wireguard

I want to be able to setup Wireguard between two WSL2 instances on the same LAN but I cannot reach connectivity between them.

I have the following setup:

- Windows network 192.168.0.0/24
- Wireguard network 10.0.0.0/24
- Machine 1 with WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 (W10 host)

  - WSL2 network 172.19.208.0/28
  - WSL2 ip interface 172.19.209.104
  - WSL2 wireguard ip 10.0.0.2/24
- Machine 2 with WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 (W10 host)

  - WSL2 network 172.27.224.0/28
  - WSL2 ip interface 172.27.234.66
  - WSL2 ip Wireguard 10.0.0.1/24

Execute on Machine 1 WSL2: `wg-quick up wg0`.

**Machine 1 Wireguard config /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf**

```bash
[Interface]
PrivateKey = blablablalbal
ListenPort = 60709
Address = 10.0.0.2/24

[Peer]
PublicKey = blablablabal
Endpoint = 192.168.0.3:42659
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.1/32
```

Execute on Machine 2 WSL2: `wg-quick up wg0`

**Machine 2 Wireguard config /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf**

```bash
[Interface]
PrivateKey = blablablalbal
ListenPort = 42659
Address = 10.0.0.1/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = blablablabal
Endpoint = 192.168.0.3:60709
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32
```

Tests:

- ping 10.0.0.1 from Machine 1 or ping 10.0.0.2 from Machine 2 does not respond.
- traceroute no info
- interfaces wg0 up on both machines
- different AllowedIPs (full Wireguard range /24..)
- portproxy from Windows host to WSL2 Wireguard ports:

```
Machine 1

netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=60709 listenaddress=192.168.0.3 connectport=60709 connectaddress=10.0.0.2
```

```bash
Machine 2

netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=42659 listenaddress=192.168.0.4 connectport=42659 connectaddress=10.0.0.1
```

Routes on Machine 1 WSL2 Ubuntu

```bash
default via 172.19.208.1 dev eth0
10.0.0.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.2
172.19.208.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.209.104
```

Routes on Machine 2 WSL2 Ubuntu

```bash
default via 172.27.224.1 dev eth0
10.0.0.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1
172.27.224.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.27.234.66
```

I think I have something missing on routing, but I dont know what else to do.
Could any give me a hint or help?

Thanks.

Comment: If I didn't miss it, you did not specify a protocol for `portproxy`. It defaults to TCP, which is not what WireGuard uses.

Answer (score 1):

Do not proxy a WireGuard interface's listen port to its own interface address. That will not work.

With WSL2, instead proxy that port to the VM's virtual NIC interface, like this on Machine 1:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=60709 listenaddress=192.168.0.3 connectport=60709 connectaddress=172.19.209.104
```

And this on Machine 2:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=42659 listenaddress=192.168.0.4 connectport=42659 connectaddress=172.27.234.66
```

Also see the answers and comments from the [Connecting to WSL2 Server Via Local Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61002681/connecting-to-wsl2-server-via-local-network) question for a variety of other approaches and tricks to proxying WSL2 connections.

And also note that you have the wrong `Endpoint` address in the WireGuard config posted for Machine 1 -- it should use the IP address for Machine 2, not Machine 1:

```
Endpoint = 192.168.0.4:42659
```